# Convert absolute or relative URL like “example.com/profile” to absolute URL, including protocol

Tags: javascript, url

I want to give users the option to input a URL into an input field. At the moment it is really strict as it only accepts absolute URLs like this: `https://example.com/a.profile`.

The users gave feedback that they also want to be able to just type a relative URL like the following: `example.com/a.profile` or `www.example.com/a.profile`.

How do you take an arbitrarily relative or absolute URL and make sure that the output is an absolute URL? The `https:` protocol can be assumed for all URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t mess around with regular expressions.
Use the [`URL` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) instead:

```js
// Solution:

const asAbsoluteURL = (url, base = location) => {
    let absoluteURL;
    
    try {
      absoluteURL = new URL(url);
    }
    catch {
      absoluteURL = new URL(`//${url}`, base);
    }
    
    return absoluteURL;
  };

// Usage:

const absoluteURL1 = asAbsoluteURL("example.com");
const absoluteURL2 = asAbsoluteURL("example.com", "http://something");
const absoluteURL3 = asAbsoluteURL("https://example.com");

console.log({    // Run this snippet and look into your browser console
  absoluteURL1,  //   for the results (hit [F12]).
  absoluteURL2,
  absoluteURL3,
  "1. If you want strings": "use concatenation: " + absoluteURL1,
  "2. Alternatively": `use template literals: ${absoluteURL2}`,
  "3. Or use the String function explicitly": String(absoluteURL3)
});

// Interactive demonstration:

addEventListener("input", () => {
  const relativeURL = document.getElementById("relativeURL").value,
    baseURL = document.getElementById("baseURL").value || location;
  let result;
  
  try {
    result = formatCode`Relative URL ${relativeURL} is converted to absolute URL ${asAbsoluteURL(relativeURL, baseURL)}.`
  }
  catch {
    result = formatCode`Either the relative URL ${relativeURL} is not a valid relative URL or the base URL ${baseURL} is not a valid absolute URL itself.`;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("output").replaceChildren(...result);
});

const formatCode = (text, ...codeTexts) => text.flatMap((text, index) => [ text, Object.assign(document.createElement("code"), { textContent: codeTexts[index] }) ]).slice(0, -1);
```

```css
#output { margin-top: 0.4em; line-height: 1.4em; white-space: pre-wrap; }
code { background: #ddd; padding: 0.2em 0.5em; border-radius: 0.2em; }
```

```html
<input id="relativeURL" type="text" placeholder="example.com">
<input id="baseURL" type="text" placeholder="https://example.com">
<div id="output">Type a relative URL in the left input and an absolute URL as a base in the right input (or leave it blank to use the current location).</div>
```

This code just tries `new URL("` *your URL* `")`.
This only works for absolute URLs, so if it works, great!
Return it.

Otherwise, it’ll throw an error, but with `try`–`catch` we simply catch it and try the next option: `new URL("//` *your URL* `", base)`.
The second argument is an absolute URL base to be used for the non-absolute URL<sup>1</sup>.
With a valid second argument provided, the first argument can now be a relative URL.
If a relative URL starts with `//`, it is interpreted as a *protocol-relative* URL, so the next component, your URL string, must be the host name.

The `base` used here is the same as the current `location`; in the Stack snippet above that’s `"https://stacksnippets.net/js"`.
You can provide any base such as `"http://example.com"` or `"http://localhost"` or even `"ftp://anything"` as a second argument to `asAbsoluteURL`.

| Call | Result (URL object with this `href`) |
| --- | --- |
| `asAbsoluteURL("example.com")` | `"https://example.com/"` |
| `asAbsoluteURL("//example.com")` | `"https://example.com/"` |
| `asAbsoluteURL("www.example.com")` | `"https://www.example.com/"` |
| `asAbsoluteURL("https://example.com")` | `"https://example.com/"` |
| `asAbsoluteURL("example.com", "http://localhost")` | `"http://example.com/"` |

---

<sup>1</sup>: To be clear:

- `example.com` is a *path-relative* URL, because with the base `https://example.net/path/file` it would result in `https://example.net/path/example.com`.
- `/example.com` is an *origin-relative* URL, because with the base `https://example.net/path/file` it would result in `https://example.net/example.com`.
- `//example.com` is a *protocol-relative* URL, because with the base `https://example.net/path/file` it would result in `https://example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I now implemented the following class, although I am not sure if I have considered all edge cases. But maybe it helps future users.

```ts
const FULL_URL_REGEX =
    /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\.\w\w+)(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
const HALF_URL_REGEX =
    /(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\.\w\w+)(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
const ASSUME_PROTOCOL = 'https';

export class URLTools {
    public static urlIsValid(url: string): boolean {
        return FULL_URL_REGEX.test(url) || HALF_URL_REGEX.test(url);
    }

    public static guaranteeFullUrl(potentiallyHalfUrl: string) {
        if (HALF_URL_REGEX.test(potentiallyHalfUrl)) {
            return `${ASSUME_PROTOCOL}://${potentiallyHalfUrl}`;
        } else if (FULL_URL_REGEX.test(potentiallyHalfUrl)) {
            return potentiallyHalfUrl;
        } else {
            throw Error('Invalid URL');
        }
    }
}
```